# What is the purpose of the operator "=>" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have seen "=>" used in some JavaScript code examples recently and have searched high and low for some explanation as to its use, but to no avail. I assume it is used for assigning values in objects, but I would like to find some documentation on it. I am new to programming and apologize if this is one of those common sense questions.

Comment: it means something entirely different in JS: an arrow function

Comment: Javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions, PHP http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: its the problem with asking 2 questions together on a Q&A site.

Comment: Yea, it gets confusing.


 - PHP: `->`  Access an object property or method.
 - JavaScript `.` Access a object property or method.
 - PHP: `=>` Set an array element.
 - JavaScript: Set an array element similar to JSON..
 - JavaScript or PHP `['bla']`  Access an array element.

Comment: Thank you for the information @Mi-Creativity. The docs are very helpful.

Comment: @Dagon Ahh, I see where I placed PhP in the question title. I should have left that off. I'll rephrase the question. It has been answered.